# Problem with deploy Nuxt.js in GitHub Pages

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, github-pages

I recently started learning `Nuxt.Js` and faced with the problem of deployment on GitHub Pages.

I do everything according to the instructions:

https://medium.com/@kozyreva.hanna/nuxt-js-gh-pages-deployment-73b88aa3aa65

Infinite `nuxt-loading` appears on `gh-pages` instead of content.

GitHub: https://github.com/Owe7x/slide

GH-pages: https://owe7x.github.io/slide/

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've already tried to follow that steps and they didn't work for me, after some researches I ended up with following steps :

1. remove the `dist` entry from `.gitignore` file
2. run `npm run generate`
3. run `git add .` then `git commit -m "deploy on gh-pages"`
4. We need to add router base configuration in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
      target: 'static',
      router: {
        base: '/<repository-name>/'
      }
```

5. run `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`

Make sure to delete the current `gh-pages` branch before running these commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot) Only now there is a problem with the paths "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

Comment: could you show a screenshot of that error?

Comment: https://ibb.co/CvgmVcx GH-Pages: https://owe7x.github.io/slide/

Comment: after running `npm run generate` go to dist/index.html and remove the slash `/` before any source link

Comment: mmmm sorry, Try this https://nuxtjs.org/faq/github-pages